# Nginx Ingress Controller Returns 404 for path other than '/' AKS - Kubernetes 1.17

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, http-status-code-404, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

I'm using kubernetes nginx ingress controller (not the nginx supported one, but the [k8s supported one](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)), with AKS (k8s version 1.17 at the moment), for which the corresponding apiversion for Ingress is `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`, therefore using [this](https://v1-14.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) documentation.

For the most basic Ingress, all fine, i.e:

```yaml
# singlebackend-ingress-rule.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 #  AKS is with 1.17, and supports only apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ingress-domain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:      
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-webapi
          servicePort: 80
```

Deployed as:

```
kubectl apply -f singlebackend-ingress-rule.yaml

curl http://ingress-domain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/health
200
{                                                         
   "me" : {                                               
      "status" : "ok",                                    
      "version" : "v15",                                  
      "appName" : "Backend.WebApi",  
      "aspNetCore_Environment" : "aks"                    
   }                                                      
}
```

However, if I **only** add `backend: /api`, and do the exact same:

```yaml
# multiplebackend-ingress-rule.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 #  AKS is with 1.17, and supports only apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ingress-domain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:      
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-webapi
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
```

Deployed as:

```
kubectl apply -f multiplebackend-ingress-rule.yaml

curl http://ingress-domain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/health

HTTP/2 404
server: nginx/1.19.1
date: Tue, 01 Sep 2020 09:24:36 GMT
content-length: 0
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
```

I get 404. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your defined route is `/health` not `/api/health`.

The path you define in your `Ingress`, must be handled by your back-end server.

Your `Ingress` sends all your requests prefixed with `/api` to your service `backend-webapi`, but it doesn't discard the path `/api` from the route itself.

So, when you send request to http://ingress-domain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/health, your service must handle `/api/health` not `/health`.

Answer (score 1):

By default nginx sends traffic to whatever is mentioned in path.You can use [`rewrite-target`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#examples) annotation to specify target URI where the traffic must be redirected.

```
# singlebackend-ingress-rule.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 #  AKS is with 1.17, and supports only apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ingress-domain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:      
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-webapi
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
```

As an alternative to `rewrite-target` you could use [app-root](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#app-root) annotation

```
# singlebackend-ingress-rule.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 #  AKS is with 1.17, and supports only apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ingress-domain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:      
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-webapi
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
```

With above change below curl should work without needing to have a http handler handling `/api/health` in the backend. You can simply have a http handler at `/health`

```
curl http://ingress-domain.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/health
```